# woocommerce hide placeholder with no image (composite product)

Tags: css, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and the composite product plugin. I currently have one composite product section that has no image with it, as this is a variable product without an image.

I need to hide the image placeholder **ONLY** if there is no image, as I have other composite products that I want to keep the placeholder.

I tried some css to resolve this but with no success, can someone please help.

Comment: Please provide a code example or post a link to your site.

Comment: .attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image { display: none; }
.attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image { display: block; }  this is completely wrong tho and I know it

Comment: I would need the HTML and CSS code, could you simply paste the HTML containing the product sections and your CSS code in here and post the link? https://codepen.io/pen

Comment: im just after css such as .product .images { display: none; }
.product.has-post-thumbnail .images { display: block; } but for a composite product placeholder instead